# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: android, react-native

i am developing sample application in react-native , i faced this issue when i was run- android emulator my sdk tool version is 25 , but i don't know how it is getting this issue please let me suggestion.

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.pom'.
            > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: \Library\Java\Home\jre\lib\security\cacerts (The system cannot find the path specified)
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.pom'.
            > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: \Library\Java\Home\jre\lib\security\cacerts (The system cannot find the path specified)
   > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.0/google-services-3.2.0.pom'.
            > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: \Library\Java\Home\jre\lib\security\cacerts (The system cannot find the path specified)
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.0/google-services-3.2.0.pom'.
            > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: \Library\Java\Home\jre\lib\security\cacerts (The system cannot find the path specified)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 4):

Your project can not access the urls to download the necessary libraries. This is most probably a gradle configuration issue.

Change your Project level `build.gradle` file like this:

```
buildscript {
repositories {

    google()
   jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'  
}
```

}

**Update**

If it doesn't work, try this too:

```
  repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
        ...
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Comment: i followed this but getting same issue!
 What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'storehealthrn'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.

Comment: Im the one who upvoted it. But I did not ask the question .

Answer (score -1):

Try Using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

and then 
clean and rebuild.